# VueJS Front-end never receives response from NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web, request, backend

I'm trying to set up a login feature in my web application, where the backend uses a MongoDB database and is done with NodeJS (express), and the front-end with VueJS. However, whenever I try to send back the response from the backend to the front-end, the front-end never seems to get it. Postman also never gets the response. Here is the code:

Backend:

```
app.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
  let qusername;
  let qpassword;
  console.log(req.body);
  await User.find({username: req.body.username}, (err,user) => {
    if (user == null){
      return res.status(400).send('User not found');
    }
    qusername = user[0].username;
    qpassword = user[0].password;
  });
  try{
    const user = { username: qusername, password: qpassword};
    await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err,res) => {
      if(err){
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
      if(res){
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 300}, (err, accessToken) => {
          console.log(accessToken);
          if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
          }
        
          console.log("before");
          res.send(accessToken);
          console.log("after");
        });
      }
      else {
        res.send('Wrong password');
      }
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

Front-end:

```
    async getToken({ commit }, { user }) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${HOST}:${PORT}/login`, user);
      const authToken = response.data;
      commit("setToken", { authToken });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

The backend is logging the correct request body, the JWT and "before", but not "after". So the problem really occurs in res.send().

Comment: You are using two variables with name "res". So you should be overwriting the variable res, when you called the function  `await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err,res)`. I think if you change the name of this var from res to another thing, your code should be fine to work again.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Danizavtz, the issue was that I had two variables named res. Changed the variable name in bcrypt.compare() from res to result and now everything works perfectly.